# What is the purpose of webkitRelativePath property in File object?

Tags: html, dom, webkit, console, fileapi

If you printout File object in Chrome console with something simple like this:

```
<input type="file" onchange="console.info(this.files);" />
```

you will see among other properties an always empty *webkitRelativePath* property:

```
fileName: "07.png"
fileSize: 33022
lastModifiedDate: Date
name: "07.png"
size: 33022
type: "image/png"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
```

What is it's purpose? And how it can be leveraged?

Comment: I won't use it, cause it's webkit specific only. So, I recommend that you find its meaning, but don't use it (don't leverage it).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's populated when using the `webkitdirectory` attribute on the file input:

```
<input type="file" webkitdirectory>
```

It only works in Chrome. This allows a user to select a folder rather than files, and every file is read recursively. The `webkitRelativePath` contains the relative path of the file within the hierarchy.

There's a demo [here](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/gdd11-modern-web-apps/index.html#15).

Comment: Is there a video record to those slides somewhere? Some interesting stuff in there.

Comment: It's not true it works only in Chrome. It is also in FF. See Browser compatibility: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/webkitRelativePath

Comment: Works everywhere nowadays it seems https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_file_webkitrelativepath